# BigQuery SQL group by based on changes to a value and date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the below data in a table A and want to output as mentioned below. I tried with lead function but couldn't get the desired result.

| id | value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 100 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 |
| 1 | 125 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 |
| 1 | 125 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 |
| 1 | 100 | 2023-01-05 | 2999-12-31 |
| 2 | 200 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 200 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2 | 200 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 |
| 2 | 250 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 |
| 2 | 250 | 2023-01-05 | 2999-12-31 |

I tried this

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    value,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value ORDER BY start_date) AS prev_end_date
  FROM
    table_a
)    
SELECT
  id,
  value,
  MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
  MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM
  temp
GROUP BY
  id,
  value,
  DATE_DIFF(start_date, prev_end_date, DAY) IS NULL
ORDER BY
  id,
  start_date;
```

I want a BigQuery query with output as below. It is more of type 2 data

| id | value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 |
| 1 | 125 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 |
| 1 | 100 | 2023-01-05 | 2999-12-31 |
| 2 | 200 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 |
| 2 | 250 | 2023-01-04 | 2999-12-31 |

Thanks and appreciate any help

Comment: And please explain the logic that your query will carry out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select id, value, 
  min(start_date) as start_date,
  max(end_date) as end_date
from (
  select *, countif(new_grp) over(partition by id order by start_date) as grp
  from (
    select *, ifnull(value != lag(value) over(partition by id order by start_date), true) as new_grp
    from your_table
  )
)
group by id, value, grp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following query

```
SELECT
  id,
  value,
  MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
  GREATEST(end_date, LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value ORDER BY start_date)) AS end_date
FROM
  table_a
```